# Vertical animation using css , jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some tabs and I want to animate the tabs content. The code is

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

How can I animate the Paris id for example to appear with a vertical slider?

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp). Also provide some more detail about what you mean by "appear with a vertical slider."

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help. We are not mind readers, we can't tell what the problem is with your code if you don't show us!